# Find number of occurrences of numbers in a vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a vector of integers. which contains numbers. I want to count the number of occurrences of every number in this vector. So what will be the optimum way to do this. As I am new to Vectors please let me know any optimum method.

Comment: Show us the code you've written...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a hash table, implemented by std::unordered_map. For example:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

void count_occurrence(std::unordered_map<int,int>& m, std::vector<int>& v){
    for (auto itr = v.begin(); itr != v.end(); ++itr){
        ++m[*itr];
    }
}

//...somewhere else
//you already have std::vector v filled
std::unordered_map<int,int> m;
count_occurrence(m, v);

//print the number of occurrences of 1
std::cout<<m[1]<<std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could sort the elements of the vector

Iterate through vector

Store the current integer as x

Compare current index to previous index.

If they are equal, increment another variable as f

If they are unequal, begin the cycle again

This of course is by no means a step by step instruction, but it contains enough direction to get you going

Answer (score 1):

To find the mode of a number of integers stored in an array/list/vector/etc. where *v* is the DS and *num* is the number of integers.
You may use the following technique:
Its simple and sober.

```
    i = 0;
    int m = 0, mode, c = 0, nc = 0;
    while(i<num)
    {
        c = 0;
        nc = v[i];
        c++;
        i++;
        while(nc == v[i])
        {
            c++;
            i++;
        }

        if(m < c)
        {
            m = c;
            mode = nc;
        }
    }
```